# Pattern to update single user interface components without reference to business logic

Tags: java, design-patterns, user-interface, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

What would be a good design to update single user interface components with business logic content?

- I have a window (UIWindow) which contains different kinds of UIComponents in it.
- I have a network traffic reader (NetworkDemon) which reads the internet traffic of my computer.
- I want to show the readed traffic in the user interface
- The NetworkDemon shall be independent from the UIComponent which shows its data.

Currently I'm using a Observer-Pattern between the UIWindow and the NetworkDemon, but I don't know how I can design my code in some way that only the single UIComponents can be used as Observer for the Observable NetworkDemon without given the UIWindow a reference to the NetworkDemon.

I have the following classes (coded as simple example that prints out the data simply on console):

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class UIWindow implements Observer {
    private UIComponent textArea;
    private UIComponent textList;

    public UIWindow() {
        textArea = new UITextArea();
        textList = new UITextList();
    }


    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        if(data instanceof String) {
            textArea.showData((String)data);                
        }
    }

}


abstract class UIComponent {

    public abstract void showData(String data);

}

class UITextArea extends UIComponent {

    @Override
    public void showData(String data) {
        System.out.println("UITextArea: " + data);
    }

}

class UITextList extends UIComponent {

    @Override
    public void showData(String data) {
        System.out.println("UITextList: " + data);      
    }

}

class NetworkDemon extends Observable {

    public void readNetworkTraffic() {
        // this sample data is readed from the network
        String data = "sampleData";
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(data);      
    }

}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIWindow window = new UIWindow();
        NetworkDemon demon = new NetworkDemon();

        demon.addObserver(window);
        demon.readNetworkTraffic();     
    }
}
```

So my problem is, how can I register the UIComponents to the NetworkDemon as Observer without introducing a dependency between the UIWindow and the NetworkDemon

Something like UIWindow window = new UIWindow(networkDemon); and then registering the components to the demon would not be okay because I would have a hard dependency between the window (UI) and the demon (Model).

Comment: There's no (simple) way to completely decouple them. What you typically do is introduce a third component, the *controller*, that separates the *view* from the *model* and standardizes the interface between the two. This way you can change out models without affecting your UI code, and change your UI code without affecting your model. See [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). There will be a hard dependency between the controller and the model, and a hard dependency between the view and controller, but not between the view and model.

Comment: You can further reduce the 'hardness' of the dependency between the controller and model by making the model implement an interface and having the controller only interact on the interface.